# Hibernate unexpectedly issues INSERT instead of throwing the javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException, when a nonexistent entity is passed to merge()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, optimistic-locking

A client application supplies a stale entity which is to be merged by Hibernate. Taking a very simple example.

```
public Entity update(Entity entity) {
    return entityManager.contains(entity) ? entity : entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

`Entity` is a detached, stale entity supplied by a web application, for example. The method is executed in an active JTA transaction (or resource local).

<sub>Optimistic locking has been enabled by introducing a [`@Version`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html) field in the entity given.</sub>

When an entity to be merged had already been deleted, `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` is expected to be thrown which does not happen. Hibernate performs `INSERT` instead which is completely unexpected. Inserting a stale entity instead of throwing the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` is something going against locking.

"Insert or update" is a story apart which should be suspended by throwing the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`, if a stale or deleted (nonexistent) entity is passed to `merge()`, if optimistic locking is implemented.

EclipseLink throws the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` as expected in case a stale or deleted / nonexistent entity is passed to `merge()`.

Is there a way to make Hibernate throw the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`, when a stale or nonexistent entity is passed to `merge()`?

I expect there should be some configurable property in `persistence.xml` to apply it globally application-wide or annotations to apply it to a specific entity.

<sub>I am currently using Hibernate 5.0.5 final.</sub>

---

Updated to Hibernate 5.0.6 final.

Comment: This is a long-standing Hibernate bug. You can vote for it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1661

Comment: The issue is about a decade old.

Comment: I think,  a new, fresh issue should be created. That issue report is very unlikely to be taken into account as it is quite old. It is a critical bug that cannot be taken lightly and needs to be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: It has been updated for Hibernate 5 and thus kept in the open bugs when the big JIRA cleaning was made, is precise, has votes, and a reproducible test case. Opening a new identical bug will either dissolve the bug or the attention, or be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try EntityManager.refresh instead EntityManager.merge, and verify if entity has a id value, if yes set new values and after EntityManager.merge, if not the entity has been deleted

something like this

```
public Entity update(Entity entity) {

    entityManager.refresh(entity);

    if (entity.getId() != null) {
        // my entity is in database
        // set my changes in entity
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    } else {
        // my entity has been deleted
        return null;
    }
}
```